# QRcode encoding indepth explaination

Tags: qr-code

I'm looking for an thorough explanation of how data is encoded into qr codes. The explanation should be specific enough that one could encode a qr code manually (as by drawing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete specificion is available from ISO, as [ISO/IEC 18004:2006](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=43655). It is not free. You can find some partial information on the internet, but not enough to create an encoding process. If you really need the detail, buy the spec.

I can tell you that the process is far too complex to carry out by hand -- the Reed-Solomon error correction calculation alone would take days and you'd not get it right :)

zxing has a [complete QR code encoder implementation](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder) which may show you enough of how the process is carried out for your purpose.